# Function call after page reload in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-router, redirect

I have a route like:

```
<Route component={Bar} path="/foo/:num"/>
```

I want to check if `num` exists in my database before rendering views inside `Bar` component. What I'm trying to do is utilizing `component mounting` functions as shown below to redirect to another route in case of invalid `num`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import { isNumExist } from '../../services/index.js';

class Bar extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    if (!isNumExist(this.props.params.num)){
      browserHistory.push('/home');
    }
  }

  render() {
    ... 
  }
}
```

Here goes `index.js`, defining `isNumExist()`:

```
let foo = [...]; // Contains an array fetched from database
function isNumExist(num){
  foo.map((element, i) => {
    if (foo[i].num == num) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Now on every page reload, the `isNumExist()` function triggers twice with `false` as output for second. So either `num` exists or not, the page redirects to the given route. Please correct me if I'm doing this in the wrong way or suggest the real issue preferably with details.

Comment: ur component name should be start with uppercase, instead of `bar`, use `Bar`

Comment: updated, it was just a typo due to replacing real code with sample code here. thanks for highlighting

Comment: Is your code executing before the database call (which I'm assuming is async) completes?

Comment: I have commented out rest of the code and just using custom array as `let foo = [...]`to make sure everything is running fine. Still having same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will always return `false` because `map` function result is not returned.

```
let foo = [...]; // Contains an array fetched from database
function isNumExist(num){
  foo.map((element, i) => {
    if (foo[i].num == num) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

`foo.map(...)` will return an array but it is not returned at any time. The function signature from the function that is inside the map function is only for that function itself.

so try :

```
let foo = [...]; // Contains an array fetched from database
function isNumExist(num){
   var good_numbers_length = 0;
   var length = foo.map((element, i) => {
    if (foo[i].num == num) {
      good_numbers_length += 1;
    }
  });
  if (good_numbers_length > 0)
  {
        return true;
  }  
  return false;
}
```

In addition, `browserHistory.push('/home');` does not create a proper redirect. Change it to something like `window.location = 'url'` or something react friendly like [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

Comment: Yes I already tried a similar thing that worked for me. I declared a variable with `false` as default value and updating it with `true` in case of valid `num` and returning the variable at the end of function.

Comment: But before redirecting, its still generating error because of invalid `num` used inside `render()`. What should i do to redirect before triggering `render()`?

Comment: Are you sure `browserHistory.push('/home');` is actually the way to create a redirect. It seems like it only modifies your history. Shouldn;t it be like `window.location = 'url'` or some equivalent?

Comment: yes just confirmed that the problem is with browserHistory, I'm gonna replace it with redirect by `react-router`. Thanks

Comment: Nice, i will attach that part to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in your react's entry point file (often name app.js or index.js) It's only called once per loading of the page.

So you just have to:

1. import your history dependency in your entry point file
2. use push function to go to '/home'